# malloc.c:2379: sysmalloc: Assertion... failed

Tags: c++, memory, malloc, new-operator, cout

Im currently writing a program that uses Heap class, to find the max value in part of array (size of part is k), which is moving in array, until reaches the end. It crushes on dataset:
3
1 2 3
1
with misstake: malloc.c:2379: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
It crushes when it tryes to cout the temp.value variable. If i cooment it, everything  works just fine

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>

#define DEFAULT_GROW 2

template<class T>
class IsLess {
public:
    bool operator()(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) const {
        return lhs < rhs;
    }
};

template<class T>
struct Node {
    T value;
    size_t index;
};


template <class T, class H = IsLess<T>>
class Heap {
public:
    Heap();
    Heap(const T* arr, size_t dataSize, H func = IsLess<T>());
    Heap(const Heap&) = delete;
    Heap(Heap&&) = delete;
    Heap operator = (const Heap&) = delete;
    Heap operator = (Heap&&) = delete;
    ~Heap();
    bool IsEmpty();
    void Insert(const T &k);
    Node<T> ExtractMax();
    Node<T> ExtractMaxByIndex(const size_t &i, const size_t &k);
    void InsertNode(const Node<T> &);

private:
    void Grow();
    void BuildHeap();
    void SiftDown(const int &i);
    void SiftUp(int i);
    size_t capacity;
    size_t size;
    Node<T>* data;
    H comparator;
};

template<class T, class H>
Heap<T, H>::Heap():
capacity(0),
size(0),
data(nullptr),
comparator(IsLess<T>())
{}

template<class T, class H>
Heap<T, H>::Heap(const T* arr, size_t dataSize, H func) {
    assert(arr != nullptr);
    assert(dataSize > 0);
    data = new Node<T>[dataSize];
    capacity = dataSize;
    size = dataSize;
    comparator = func;
    // std::memcpy(data->value, arr, dataSize * sizeof(T) - 1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < dataSize; ++i) {
        data[i].value = arr[i];
        data[i].index = i;
    }
    BuildHeap();
}

template<class T, class H>
Heap<T, H>::~Heap() {
    delete[] data;
}

template<class T, class H>
void Heap<T, H>::Grow() {
    if (capacity == 0) {
        data = new Node<T>[++capacity];
        return;
    }
    if (size < capacity) {
        return;
    }
    capacity *= DEFAULT_GROW;
    Node<T> *buf = new Node<T>[capacity];
    std::memcpy(buf, data, sizeof(Node<T>) * size - 1);
    delete[] data;
    data = buf;
}

template<class T, class H>
void Heap<T, H>::SiftDown(const int &i) {
    size_t leftChild = i * 2 + 1;
    size_t rightChild = i * 2 + 2;
    size_t largest = i;
    if(leftChild < size
    && comparator(data[largest].value, data[leftChild].value)) {
        largest = leftChild;
    }
    if(rightChild < size
    && comparator(data[largest].value, data[rightChild].value)) {
        largest = rightChild;
    }
    if(largest != i) {
        std::swap(data[i], data[largest]);
        SiftDown(largest);
    }
}

template<class T, class H>
void Heap<T, H>::SiftUp(int i) {
    while(i > 0) {
        int parent = (i - 1) / 2;
        if(comparator(data[i].value, data[parent].value)) {
            return;
        }
        std::swap(data[i], data[parent]);
        i = parent;
    }
}

template<class T, class H>
void Heap<T, H>::BuildHeap() {
    for (int i = size / 2 - 1 ; i >= 0 ; --i) {
        SiftDown(i);
    }
}

template<class T, class H>
bool Heap<T, H>::IsEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
}

template<class T, class H>
void Heap<T, H>::Insert(const T &k) {
    if (IsEmpty() || size == capacity) {
        Grow();
    }
    data[size].value = k;
    data[size].index = size;
    SiftUp(size++);
}

template<class T, class H>
Node<T> Heap<T, H>::ExtractMax() {
    assert(!IsEmpty());
    Node<T> result = data[0];
    data[0] = data[--size];
    if (!IsEmpty()) {
        SiftDown(0);
    }
    return result;
}

template<class T, class H>
void Heap<T, H>::InsertNode(const Node<T> &node) {
    if (IsEmpty() || size == capacity) {
        Grow();
    }
    data[size] = node;
    SiftUp(size++);
}

template<class T, class H>
Node<T> Heap<T, H>::ExtractMaxByIndex(const size_t &i, const size_t &k) {
    assert(!IsEmpty());
    Node<T> result = {0, i + k + 1}; //  чтобы условие не выполнилось с 1 раза
    Node<T> *extracted = new Node<T>[k];
    size_t extractedIndex = 0;
    while(result.index < i || result.index > i + k - 1) {
        result = ExtractMax();
        extracted[extractedIndex++] = result;
    }
    for (size_t j = 0 ; j < extractedIndex ; ++j) {
        InsertNode(extracted[j]);
    }
    delete [] extracted;
    return result;
}

void Answer (unsigned int *arr, const size_t &n, const size_t &i, const size_t &k) {
    assert(arr != nullptr);
    Heap<unsigned> heap(arr, n);
    //size_t resSize = n - k + 1;

    Node<unsigned int> temp = heap.ExtractMaxByIndex(i, k);
    std::cout << temp.value << " ";  // This line causes the misstake
}

int main() {
    size_t n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;
    unsigned int *arr = new unsigned int[n];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cin >> arr[i];
    }
    size_t k = 0;
    std::cin >> k;
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < 1 ; ++i) {
        Answer(arr, n, i, k);
    }
    delete[] arr;
    return 0;
}

Input: 
3
1 2 3
1

Output:
1 2 3
```

Comment: That's a lot of code.  Can you reduce it to a [mcve]?

Comment: Either use a `std::vector<Node<T>>`, or look at `Node<T> *extracted = new Node<T>[k];` - is `extractedIndex` ever greater than `k`? Also, please [edit] into your question the data you are inputting.

Comment: Note there are many tools to find dynamic memory errors - almost always either overrunning an array or using an object after it's deleted.  valgrind is a popular one on many systems.  If you're going to code in C++, especially with raw pointers, you'll want to get familiar with these as early as possible.

Comment: Btw, valgrind immediately shows that @KenY-N is exactly right about the bug.  You could have found it in seconds by using the right tools.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this part of code:

```
template<class T, class H>
Node<T> Heap<T, H>::ExtractMaxByIndex(const size_t& i, const size_t& k)
{
    assert(!IsEmpty());
    Node<T> result = { 0, i + k + 1 }; //  чтобы условие не выполнилось с 1 раза
    Node<T>* extracted = new Node<T>[k]; <- right here
    size_t extractedIndex = 0;
    while (result.index < i || result.index > i + k - 1)
    {
        result = ExtractMax();
        extracted[extractedIndex++] = result; <- and right here
    }
    for (size_t j = 0; j < extractedIndex; ++j)
    {
        InsertNode(extracted[j]);
    }
    delete[] extracted;
    return result;
}
```

First, you are allocating less memory than needed (in your sample, `k` is 1), then you try to assign a value in memory that is out of bounds of your allocated dynamic memory here:

```
extracted[extractedIndex++] = result;
```